# Error ExpansionTile is not working or stack (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tile, expansion

I'm trying to solve an issue; however, it still not working and I'm getting the same error.
I hope  someone could give me an answer, thanks.

Code

```
  child: FirestoreListView<MainCategory>(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    query: mainCategoryCollection(widget.selectedCat),
                    itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
                      MainCategory mainCategory = snapshot.data();
                      return ExpansionTile(
                          title: Text(mainCategory.mainCategory!),
                        children: [
                          SubCategoryWidget(
                            selectedSubCat: mainCategory.mainCategory,
                          ),
                        
                        ],
                        );
                    },
                  ),
);
```

}
}
`

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library ===================================================== The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 1840 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    ExpansionTile
> ExpansionTile:file:///C:/Users/faruq/AndroidStudioProjects/foodcourtapp/lib/category/main_category_widget.dart:26:34
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1840:12)
>
> #3      RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:437:14)
>
> #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
>
> #6      _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
>
> #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #8      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering /layout_helper.dart:56:11)
>
> #9      RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
>
> #10     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
>
> #11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #12     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:233:12)
>
> #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering /proxy_box.dart:116:14)
>
> #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
>
> #17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
>
> #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #20     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:213:28)
>
> #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #22     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
>
> #23     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
>
> #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
>
> #25     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
>
> #26     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
>
> #27     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
>
> #28     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1757:7)
>
> #29     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
>
> #30     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:504:19)
>
> #31     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:892:13)
>
> #32     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
>
> #33     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
>
> #34     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
>
> #35     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
>
> #39     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
>
> #40     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
>
> #41     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
>
> (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
>
> The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was
> fired:
>
> RenderPositionedBox#62a81 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> ...  parentData:  (can use size)
>
> ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=312.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
>
> ...  size: Size(312.7, 0.0)
>
> ...  alignment: Alignment.center
>
> ...  textDirection: ltr
>
> ...  widthFactor: expand
>
> ...  heightFactor: 1.0
>
> RenderObject: RenderPositionedBox#62a81 relayoutBoundary=up9
> NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS- COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> parentData:  (can use size)
>
> constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=312.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
>
> size: Size(312.7, 0.0)
>
> alignment: Alignment.center
>
> textDirection: ltr
>
> widthFactor: expand
>
> heightFactor: 1.0
>
> ...  child: RenderOffstage#06e2c relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS- UPDATE
>
> ...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
>
> ...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=312.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
>
> ...    size: MISSING
>
> ...    offstage: false
>
> ...    child: RenderPadding#fba79 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING- BITS-UPDATE
>
> ...      parentData:  (can use size)
>
> ...      constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=312.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
>
> ...      size: MISSING
>
> ...      padding: EdgeInsets.zero
>
> ...      textDirection: ltr
>
> ...      child: RenderFlex#d4c2f relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS- UPDATE
>
> ...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
>
> ...        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=312.7,
> 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
>
> ...        size: MISSING
>
> ...        direction: vertical
>
> ...        mainAxisAlignment: start
>
> ...        mainAxisSize: max
>
> ...        crossAxisAlignment: center
>
> ...        verticalDirection: down
>
> ...        child 1: RenderRepaintBoundary#79e1d NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-
>
> BITS-UPDATE
>
> ...          needs compositing
>
> ...          parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1;
> fit=FlexFit.tight
>
> ...          constraints: MISSING
>
> ...          size: MISSING
>
> ...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never
> painted)
>
> ...        child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#42f8a NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-PAINT
>
> ...          parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
>
> ...          constraints: MISSING
>
> ...          size: MISSING
>
> ...          additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity,
> h=0.0)

Comment: wrap with sized box with providing size. Can include more about `FirestoreListView`.s parent widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can u give some example pls, sir

Comment: If you are using `FirestoreListView` inside column, try wrapping `Expanded(child:FirestoreListView(..)` and test without `ExpansionTile`. If it works, try wrapping another sizedBox or `Exapned` on `ExpansionTile`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `FirestoreListView` with `SizedBox` and add a *height* to the later; if `FirestoreListView`'s parent is a *box*(*SizedBox*, *Container*, *ConstrainedBox*... ), add *height* to the parent instead.

Comment: sorry, it's still not working, because the problem is in **expansion tile**, when i click the arrow to open down, it cannot open and show nothing @fsbelinda

Comment: Is there errors or warnings? Does `SubCategoryWidget` have a size (width, height)?